# sapling tree gen problems 2.8

Tags: python, add-on

The problem occured unexpectedly and appears only in one particular .blend file. After shift-a then curve>sapling tree gen no new object is created. Info shows up, pointing three lines in py's and that one object "Cube.013_Cube.000" is not visible (?) or simply missing.

[image]

I tried making a copy of that file, then deleting all objects and seeing if it helps, gives the same info.
I tried downloading different blender version and still in that one particular file add on seems to have problem, in any other .blend it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found many interesting things
objects supposedly not being invisible in RenderLayer were not visible in any view, moreover, in the outliner. I tried searching for them by trying to append anything, from another .blend blank file. I suprisingly found that a lot of mesh data was in the scene, but it wasn't connected to any object, thus confusing the add on py's. After cleaning not used, hidden mesh data, add on started working properly.